# Old-Persian Numeral System

Tags: numerals

Does any body know how old-Persian numeral were used and provide some example?

[image]

(source of image is Unicode characters maps)

Comment: Your question seems a little too broad... :) The answerer would need to make a research for each of these (unless there is a common resource, but I doubt that).

Comment: I was going to point you at Daniels & Bright, _The World's Writing Systems_, but I find that though it covers scripts of those names, it doesn't have anything on numerical notation for them.

Comment: Are you interested in the ideographs (how they were written) or how they were pronounced?

Comment: As something to start with (on Old Persian), pp. 256-258, also Table 7.17 and Figure 7.2 in Chrisomalis, Stephen. 2010. Numerical notation: A comparative history. Cambridge: CUP. http://www.cambridge.org/us/knowledge/isbn/item2709599/?site_locale=en_US

Comment: @AlexB. I am interested in how these is used in counting. For example how to write 453 is theses number

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks to reference, currently I do not have access to that book, but I will investigate on it as soon as possible

Comment: Old Persian numerals were treated somewhat like Roman numerals: they were based on juxtaposition, and not place-value; unlike Roman they were right-to-left. So "5" was 2 2 1 and "18" was 10 2 2 2 2. 
Decimal 453 would have been 100 100 100 100 20 20 20 10 2 1. See http://sites.la.utexas.edu/persian_online_resources/history-of-the-language/old-persian-script/ I have no idea about the other scripts.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Thanks, How you define direction for numerals? Direction of Old Persian Numerals are Like Arabic numerals. I think Arabic and Old-Persian numerals are both from left to right, and roman numerals are almost left to right, 4,5,6 -> IV, V, VI, indeed if while righting a number you place most value number in left it starts on the left and so it right to left

Comment: @MarkBeadles  "5" was 2 2 1 in Roman? Wasn't 5 simply V?

Comment: @Alenanno "somewhat like" Roman, but not identical. The numerals I listed work for Old Persian. Yes, Roman had symbols for 5, 50, 500 instead of 2, 20

Comment: @Reza Yes, I put that badly. I should say that unlike Roman, the numerals were always place in a single direction. You're right, it's ambiguous to call it right-to-left :) Perhaps largest-value-on-the-left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Old Persian numerals](http://sites.la.utexas.edu/persian_online_resources/history-of-the-language/old-persian-script/) were treated somewhat like Roman numerals: they were based on *juxtaposition* or *[addition](http://www.math.uh.edu/~mflagg/2303Text/2303-Section-11.pdf)*[PDF], and not *[place-value](http://www.math.uh.edu/~mflagg/2303Text/2303-Section-13.pdf)* [PDF] like Arabic, Mayan, or Bablylonian numerals

Unlike Roman, the numerals were always placed in a single direction (largest-value-on-the-left); there was no subtractive notation like IV for 4. Also, Roman had symbols for 5 (V), 50 (L), 500 (D) instead of 2, 20.

So n Old Persian, "5" was `2 2 1` and "18" was `10 2 2 2 2`. Decimal `453` would have been `100 100 100 100 20 20 10 2 1`.